# C# Which if is the priority for an else if

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this specific piece of code in my project:

```
if (type == 1)
    if (line.StartsWith(user.PadRight(FieldLengths1[0])))
        keep = true;
    else if (type == 2)
        if (line.StartsWith(user.PadRight(FieldLengths2[0])))
            keep = true;
```

Originally, the indenting was different. The else-if is supposed to to be linked to "if (type == 1)", as the content would suggest. But Visual Studio seems to have changed my indentation to suggest that it is instead linked to the next if (if (line.startswith...))

This could be equivalent to

```
if (type == 1)
{
    if (line.StartsWith(user.PadRight(FieldLengths1[0])))
        keep = true;
}
else if (type == 2)
{
    if (line.StartsWith(user.PadRight(FieldLengths2[0])))
        keep = true;
}
```

Or to this:

```
if (type == 1)
{
    if (line.StartsWith(user.PadRight(FieldLengths1[0])))
        keep = true;
    else if (type == 2)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(user.PadRight(FieldLengths2[0])))
            keep = true;
    }
}
```

I would like to know how does the else-if behave without brackets, and what exactly decides which if it would be linked to?

Comment: When you have doubts like this just use the enclosing braces.

Comment: The indentation isn´t needed at all for deciding which branch is executed (opposed to python for instance). Actually you could even the exact same code if it were written in one single line without any indentation or line-breaks. However you can easily check this out using your debugger.

Comment: That's what I did, but I was wondering how it worked on the level of the language

Comment: @HimBromBeere But the point here is that VS's code formatted changed the indentation from what he had to something that suggested that it did something different from what was expected; so mentioning the indentation was just explaining how they noticed the problem, rather than suggesting that changing the indentation changed what the code did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [C# 5.0 Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) states in §8.7.1

> An `else` part is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if`
>   that is allowed by the syntax.

Answer (score 6):

The `else` keyword is always linked to the closest `if`.

You should use braces to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the if statement is a one-liner?
``if (b) b = false;``

Comment: @RandRandom What is so unclear with "always" and "closest"

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(v=vs.71).aspx says:

```
pp-conditional:   pp-if-section   pp-elif-sectionsopt   pp-else-sectionopt   pp-endif
```

So, else keyword is matched greedy to the closest if.